# Cloud2Edge installation

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-ditto, hono

I have been trying to install the package eclipse cloud2edge on wsl2 with no luck so far. I have followed the steps mentionned in the official web site, but when i try installling it using the helm chart with the debug flag it's stuck at : service kafka-0-extarnal does not have load balancer ingress IP address.

[bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQGLt.png)

https://www.eclipse.org/packages/packages/cloud2edge/installation/

Comment: please put your error as text not screenshot

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem with the Kafka service and the loadbalancer. If you are using Minikube, you absolutely have to use NodePort.

I'm still looking for the error, I haven't found the solution yet but I solved it by changing the protocol from Kafka to AMQP. Please use this command to switch the communication to AMQP.

```
helm install -n $NS --wait --timeout 15m --set hono.messagingNetworkTypes[0]=amqp --set hono.useLoadBalancer=false --set hono.kafkaMessagingClusterExample.enabled=false --set hono.amqpMessagingNetworkExample.enabled=true $RELEASE eclipse-iot/cloud2edge
```

Kind regards.
Kamal

Comment: Hello Kamal, thank you very much for your answer. I did try to install it on a microk8s CLUSTER with the command you suggested but now it is stuck on a different error concerning the DITTO MONGODB pod : cloud2edge/ditto-mongodb. 0 out of 1 expected pods are ready, note that the hono services are ready, but not the ditto ones

Comment: Hello Anouar, 

Could you please share the deployment of your mongodb service? 
Thank you